# Ext.ComponentQuery.query Questions

Tags: javascript

Originally, to define Editable User Details and Read-Only User details this is what they provided:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > textfield').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > fieldcontainer > textfield').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > fieldcontainer > checkboxfield').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
```

(and the same but setReadOnly(false) for editable fields).
I am attempting to create another controller using the same format for editable fields. However, it is overriding it and is not displaying certain fields.

I changed it to this format:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > fieldcontainer > textfield[firstName]').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > fieldcontainer > textfield[middleName]').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > fieldcontainer > textfield[lastName]').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > textfield[intranetId]').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#UserDetailsPanel > textfield[emailId]').forEach(function(component){
            component.setReadOnly(true);
        });
```

This solves the issue of overriding, as all values are now displayed; however, now you cannot edit the fields.

Any help? How do I solve this problem?